# Triggering event handler from button href

Tags: jquery

I'm using Jquery steps which is a wizard plugin.  As it doesn't fully support nested wizards, within some of the steps i want to switch between nav tabs rather than the wizard moving to the next step.

I've changed the href of the button from '#next' to 'nextMETab' which has worked using the following code:

```
$("#wizard-form .actions a[href='#next']").prop("href", "#nextMETab");
```

How can i trigger an event handler from a click on the button?

Many thanks

Comment: You want to simulate a click event for a button. Isn't it?

Comment: sounds like you'll need to unbind the old event and bind the new event back to the link

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's quite unclear what your trying to achieve here but this may be what your after:

```
$("#wizard-form .actions a[href='#nextMETab']").click(function() {

})
```

Comment: Thanks, ive already tried this though and it doesnt fire on the button click

Comment: Sorted, i placed the event in a function after where i changed the button href. Originally i had placed the event in document ready. Thanks